# GSMTaskManager onRunTask calls MainActivity method?

Tags: android, methods, periodic-task, gcmtaskservice

I have an app that the `MainActivity` has a method (called `doUpdate()`) that is called from a button hit.  This uses the `MainActivity`'s public variables to access a database, perform some updates, and update some records.   This works well.

We now need to automate this with a `PeriodicTask` as well.

I created a `GCMTaskManager` service as follows:

```
public class MyPeriodicTaskService extends GcmTaskService {
  public MyPeriodicTaskService() {
  }

  @Override
  public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    Log.i("MYLOG","Task Running...");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

In my MainActivity, `onCreate()`, I setup the `PeriodicTask` as follows:

```
 GcmNetworkManager networkManager=GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);
 PeriodicTask task=new PeriodicTask.Builder()
    .setService(MyPeriodicTaskService.class)
    .setPeriod(60)
    .setFlex(30)
    .setRequiresCharging(true)
    .setTag("UpdateSchedule")
    .build();
 networkManager.schedule(task);
```

By watching the LOG, I know that the `onRunTask()` fires periodically as I hoped.

Now I need to call my `MainActivity` method... `doUpdate()`.   Because this method is declared `PUBLIC` `VOID` and not `STATIC`, I can't call it from the services `doRunTask()`.   If I attempt to make it a `STATIC` `PUBLIC` `VOID` then the `MainActivity` variables can't be accessed properly as needed for the internal processing steps.

How do I get around this... any recommendations?

Comment: Use localbroadcastmanager or use binder/messenger for communication.

Here is a sample code with explanation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample

Comment: Is one method better than the other (or simpilier)?   I just need to "run" the doUpdate() method in the MainActivity when the onRunTask fires.   Looking at the sample code, I am not 100% sure what I need of it, to do just this.